# OCMock testing the address of a struct

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I have some code I want to test that is passing around the address of a struct:

```
MyObject myObject = ...;
MyRecord record = [someObject record];  //record is a @property
[myObject add:&record];
```

I've mocked `someObject` to return a record:

```
MyRecord record = ...;
[[[_mockSomeObject stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(record)] record];
[[_mockMyObject expect] add:&record];
```

Unfortunately, OCMock fails (I believe) because pulling the struct out of the NSValue wrapper will always return a different address.

Is there a way to get an expectation to work correctly if one of the parameters is an address of a struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [this post on returning structs](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/ocmock-return-a-struct/) with OCMock. Looks like the OCMOCK_VALUE macro just won't cut it.